# Cannot get a Google Site verified despite a valid Analytics Tracking ID

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console

I have created a web site on the Google platform: ...sites.google.com/site/golfshotpilot/ Furthermore I have made all administrational steps to get the site's analytics. In this context I got a Tracking ID. The tracking works. I get the reports and statistics. (Evidences below). However when I use the Google Webmaster Tool, the system will not verify my account for my own website. I have tried the verification based on the uploaded HTML file. It did not work. Then I tried to apply the authentication via my Tracking ID of the Analytics Tool. This did not work either. The error message is: The Google Analytics tracking code on your site looks malformed. How can this be when the tracking id is obviously OK?

Any ideas for help?

Error message
[image: Webmaster page with error]

Definition about the Analytics in the site management settings. 
(here was a hardcopy but I can insert only two )

Statistic result OK:
(here was a hardcopy but I can insert only two )

Evidence that the code is existing in the web sites source data: 
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you see in your image there is "Alternative Methods" to verifying your domain with Google. Why don't you try one of the other methods available rather than inserting the code in the head section.

Comment: @DwillX Why? Because if Google can't verify its own code, maybe there is a deeper problem that's more critical than the verification.

Comment: Can you not select from the alternative methods to use another Google account as verification.  Ie) if you have either webmaster console, tag manager, etc connected you can just verify by selecting that can you not?